# Block app internet access through app ops hidden menu

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, permissions

I'm on lollipop and want to deny some apps to use the INTERNET permission.
How do I block them? In the hidden app ops menu there is no INTERNET permission.
Do I need another app for that?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [Net Blocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.NetBlocker):

> This app is used to prevent apps from accessing the Internet, either
>   Wi-Fi or mobile data (GPRS/3G/4G).